# vuex store token doesn't update accross components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have the following store/index.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex)

const state = {
  token: null
}
const mutations = {
  setToken (state, token) {
    state.token = token
    localStorage.setItem('token', token)
  },
  removeToken (state) {
    state.token = null
    localStorage.removeItem('token')
  }
}
const getters = {
  isLoggedIn: state => {
    return state.token != null
  }
}
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  getters,
  mutations
})
```

and in my main.js I add it as such:

```
import store from './store'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

and when I login I set the token as such:

```
this.$store.commit('setToken', response.data.token)
```

Which should be working because the setToken function successfully save it to localStorage.

However, if I go to my other components and call:

```
data () {
  return {
    loggedIn: false
  }
},  
mounted: function () {
  this.loggedIn = this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn
  console.log(this.loggedIn)
}
```

then console will print 'false'. I have also tried to change 'mounted' to 'computed', 'created' and 'ready' but the result is the same.

I can only seem to solve the problem if I do like this:

```
mounted: function () {
  this.token = localStorage.getItem('token')
  this.$store.commit('setToken', this.token)
},
computed: {
  isLoggedIn () {
    return this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn
  }
}
```

for which isLoggedIn will finally be true.

But if I do like that then what's the point of vuex..

I'm thinking I either do something wrong with not knowing whether to call computed/mounted/etc, or maybe the way I do mutations is wrong, or maybe I don't initialize Vuex in the proper file.. but I feel like I've tried it all now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component is probably mounted **before** you login and set the token.

Seeing as you're using local storage for token persistence, I would initialise the value that way, ie

```
const state = {
  token: localStorage.getItem('token')
}
```

This will be `null` if it has not been set (or has been removed).

Comment: Wow, this works perfectly! Thanks a lot <3.. by the way, should I use mounted or computed (or something else) when I call stuff like `this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn`?

Comment: @fisker Not really sure what you mean there. `mounted` and `computed` are two very different things.